# Is it true that the image of a perfect set is perfect under a continuous map?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

It is well-known that the image of a compact set is compact and the image of a connected set is connected under a continuous map. Here $A$ is perfect if $A$ it is equal to the derived set of itself.

I would like to ask if this property holds for perfect set. i.e

> The image of a perfect set is perfect under a continuous map.

Thank you so much!

Comment: And your definition of a set $A$ to be perfect is that $A'=A$ holds?

Comment: Hi @HennoBrandsma, Yeap  "$A$ is perfect if $A$ it is equal to the derived set of itself"

Comment: Or equivalently that $A$ is closed ($A'\subseteq A$) without isolated points ($A \subseteq A'$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Consider the image of $\Bbb R$ under $\arctan$ (as a subset of $\Bbb R$).

For compact sets, the boundedness property lets closed sets remain closed, so compactness is preserved. However, the property of no isolated points is not enough to preserve closedness, and thus perfect-ness (perfection? perfectity?) is not preserved in general.

Comment: The image of $\Bbb R$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$ (when I consider that to be the codomain of $\arctan$) so closedness is not preserved for unbounded sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Preservation of closedness is like surjectivity, in that basically the same function can either have the property or not depending on exactly what you specify as the codomain.

Answer (score 4):

No, any compact metric space $X$ is the continuous image of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, the Cantor cube, which is perfect. So also for the non-perfect $X=\{0,1\}$ (projection ) or the non-perfect $X=[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ etc.

This gives perfect maps from a perfect space with non-perfect image.